# Getting the value of a specific cell from a selected row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, grid, selection, cells

I have the following code from selected rows in a grid......

```
var selected_rows = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
    Ext.each(selected_rows,function(item) {

    var left_thumbnail_jpeg_name =item.data.left;

    var right_thumbnail_jpeg_name = //select second cell along row
```

Can someone tell me how to set the second cell value along the row to a variable?

James

Comment: What kind of grid, a table? What library are you using?

Comment: Do you want to GET a value or SET a value? The title says get, but the question says set. It's an important distinction.

Comment: just want to pass the value to the variable, no setting or getting across client / server required.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your tags did not include ExtJS and that is a bit misleading.

As for your question, since your grid in bound to a store of records you only need to change a record value for it to be imminently rendered to the grid.

in your case it will be :

```
item.set('right', YOUR NEW VALUE);
```

assuming that the next column is named right and that you have the new new value.